# Performance difference between DirectoryStream and File.list() in travesing folder

Tags: java, directory, java-7

Is there any performance difference between DirectoryStream and File.list()

I have tried to strace both java program in Linux platform, it makes use of getdents64 system call with same parameters. It looks to me both have same performance but different programming paradigm

Comment: DirectoryStream is new to me since I'm still learning the Java API, but it seems to me that your answer is in your question: _different programming paradigm_

Answer (score 2):

You might find this interesting:

[Mapping java.io.File Functionality to java.nio.file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html#mapping)

Answer (score 2):

The performance benefit of `DirectoryStream` come in the form of memory usage and the ability handle the returned path objects as the directory is being listed rather than building the full list and storing it in memory, then iterating over it.  This is beneficial when listing directories containing large numbers of files, or when recursively walking a directory tree.

More info here: http://blog.eyallupu.com/2011/11/java-7-working-with-directories.html

Answer (score 1):

If they both call the same system call why would there be a difference? Traversing a directory is fundamentally I/O bound.